# How to Install IronPython Studio

Tags: visual-studio, ironpython

I am stuck with IronPython Studio Installation. It needs VS 2008 Shell Isolated Mode Redistributable Package. So i downloaded that and installed in my C:\Program Files. Then I ran IronPython Studio Isolated.msi but it says that

> This setup requires Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Shell Isolated Mode Redistributable Package. Please install Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Shell Isolated Mode Redistributable Package and run this setup again.

I have Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate in my PC.
OS is Windows 8 32 bit.

Comment: Please try to search a bit longer the next time as there seem to be questions relating to similar issues and the abandonment as old as five years: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1920596/468244

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at [Python Tools for Visual Studio](http://pytools.codeplex.com/). It is a very active IDE project for IronPython supporting various visual studio versions.

Is there any specific reason why you want to use [IronPython Studio](https://ironpythonstudio.codeplex.com/)? The project seems to have been abandoned six years ago and is unlikely to work with recent versions of visual studio and IronPython.

Comment: I have a book named Pro IronPython 2009 and in that book the author teaches with IronPython Studio. And IronPython Stusio is a visual studio like drag and drop IDE. I like ease of use in Visual studio. I like the simplicity of python. IronPython Studio can mix these two things up. But it is very sad that these type of projects have been abandoned ver long.

Comment: In your link, it is about IronPython. Not for IronPython Studio.

Comment: In most aspects, PTVS (Python Tools for Visual Studio) replaces IronPython Studio and offers the same features and even more. If *a visual studio like drag and drop IDE* refers to a WPF (no winforms) GUI designer, PTVS has that. You could also read what actual experts on IronPython and its ecosystem are saying in related discussions: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2978656/468244) and [there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2978141/468244)

Answer (score 0):

After installing the *Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Shell Isolated Mode Redistributable Package*, go to the `c:\` drive. At the root level you will find the folder `VS 2008 Shell Redist\Isolated Mode`. Here is the real installation file named `vs_shell_isolated.enu.exe`. Install it!

After completing that installation, you will be able to install *IronPython Studio 1.0*.